# Need help with OracleDB SQL Developer Regular Expression Query

Tags: sql, oracle

When I let this Query run in my Oracle SQL Developer 1.5.3

```
select 
  COLUMNNAME , 
  REPLACE( COLUMNNAME, 'BEFORESTRING', 'AFTERSTRING' ) 
    as COLUMNNAME
from 
  TABLENAME
;
```

This ain't working. Does anyone know what's wrong with the Query? Or maybe the Oracle DB Developer Tool has a bug?

Update: I want to change the table not only print out a regex match.

Comment: Can you explain "ain't working"? What is not working? Are you getting wrong output?

Comment: The Output I get is in the Results Panel, with the all the data fields from COLUMNNAME and not only the BEFORESTRING but the whole data field like bla0_BEFORESTRING_bla_bla2_bla3_bla4. Then I refresh the view of the table and see the old state, without any changes.

Comment: +1 (for Cybernate).  Also, what is "the Oracle DB Developer Tool"?  I have never heard of such a product.

Comment: The query looks fine as such.. and if you think the output still showing BEFORESTRING then I think the problem could be with the Data in the table (maybe there is not data field with value BEFORESTRING)...

Comment: You haven't changed the table, if that's what you thought.  You just selected from it.

Comment: -1 for Tony ;) - Google is your friend - First hit: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html And +1 for Tony, yes I want to change the table, selecting is not what I want. alter table does not compute or at least i never did it before, I am new to this.

Comment: I didn't say I hadn't heard of _an_ Oracle DB developer tool, or of SQL Developer.  You called it "the Oracle DB Developer Tool", which looked like a product name what with all the capitalization!

Comment: You need an UPDATE statement.

Comment: Ermm yea ok, we can discuss now all day about that bloddy tool or you can point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Done.  I was pointing out that your question was not helpful to those of us inclined to answer it by being vague about both the problem and the environment.  But anyway...

Comment: @StephanKristyn - it's generally not a good idea to atagonise people who you want to help you.  If you phrase your question ambiguously or don't give us sufficient detail, you must expect us to ask questions and you should answer them gladly.  Or not: the choice is yours.  It just depends on whether you want a solution.

Comment: Thanks Tony for the answer, it worked like a charm. I still have to read a lot of documentation about OracleDB. And you are right, my question didn't state the result I was expecting, please accept my sincere apologies. @APC Thanks for your "contribution" to my thread. I think to describe me as antagonising is a bit harsh. I just wanted to quit arguing about the tool, you couldn't see me smiling while writing - maybe I should have added an explanation to the smiley in my answer, what it means, how to interpret Netiquette and so forth.

Comment: Thanks Tony 4 the answer, it worked like a charm. I still have to read a lot of OracleDB docs. You were right, my question didn't state the result I was expecting, please accept my apologies. @APC Thanks for your "contribution". I think to describe me as antagonising is a bit harsh. I just wanted to quit arguing about the tool, you couldn't see me smiling while writing - in a perfect world you would have seen that I was happy about Tony's timely reply. Maybe I should have added a better explanation to the smiley in my answer, what it means, how to interpret Netiquette and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
update tablename
set columnname =  REPLACE( COLUMNNAME, 'BEFORESTRING', 'AFTERSTRING' ) ;
```

That will change all rows unless you add a WHERE clause.  If there is a lot of data this would be more efficient:

```
update tablename
set columnname =  REPLACE( COLUMNNAME, 'BEFORESTRING', 'AFTERSTRING' ) 
where columnname like '%BEFORESTRING%';
```